Can pypiserver distinguish the client python version and give the corresponding dependency package?
I privately deployed a pypiserver and uploaded some wheel packages. We use different python versions in different operating systems. These packages are adapted for multiple operating systems.
The following scenario exists: When installing the kubernetes module, you need to install the websocket-client dependency.
There are three different versions of websocket-client in pypiserver:
# http://<pypiserver>/simple/websocket-client/
# display as follow:
Links for websocket-client
websocket_client-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
websocket_client-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
websocket_client-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl

pip3 should install websocket-client 1.8.0 when client python version > 3.8
pip3 should install websocket-client 1.6.1 when client python version < 3.8
but in some os use python 3.7.9, execute pip3 install kubernetes -i <private-pypiserver-addr> i got:
[root@host-169 ~]# pip3 install kubernetes -i http://<pypiserver>/simple --trusted-host <pypiserver-host>
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Looking in indexes: http://<pypiserver>/simple
Collecting kubernetes
  Downloading http://<pypiserver>/packages/kubernetes-29.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 69.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kubernetes) (1.12.0)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.4.1 (from kubernetes)
  Downloading http://<pypiserver>/packages/PyYAML-6.0.1.tar.gz (125kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 64.9MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
Collecting certifi>=14.05.14 (from kubernetes)
  Downloading http://<pypiserver>/packages/certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 60.6MB/s 
Collecting websocket-client!=0.40.0,!=0.41.*,!=0.42.*,>=0.32.0 (from kubernetes)
  Downloading http://<pypiserver>/packages/websocket_client-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 52.0MB/s 
websocket-client requires Python '>=3.8' but the running Python is 3.7.9
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 24.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Is there a way for me to make the client in the python 3.7.9 environment pull the 1.6.1 dependency instead of the 1.8.0 dependency?
Or pypiserver should be replaced some other component can do it?
What confuses me is that there is no such problem when pulling from the official source.

PyPI.org provide JSON API (like this) which pip uses to find out what releases of a package require what Python version (field requires_python). Does your pypiserver provides the same? If not — pip cannot determine required Python version and downloads the latest release. That cannot be fixed at the server side.
